# How can I correctly serialize Datetime from an Ajax call inside an IEnumerble list of objects that have a Datetime property

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

So I have a IEnumerable list of an object in my View as my model. The object has fields such as strings, ints, bools, and Datetime. I want to serialize that list but the issue is that everything is done correctly except for the Datetime and for some reason it serializes into an incorrect number of ticks resulting in the wrong date when I print it out in my Controller. So I have a variety of dates either June or July 2019 and they all become 01/00/1900. This is being used to export DataTable entries into an Excel sheet.

I have tried iterating through the IEnumerable list with several methods but none work in getting access to the datetime property properly so I cannot just make a second list of those date times.

```
$("#btnExport").on("click", function () {
      var modelData = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ExportTransactionsInExcel", "Gatelog")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: modelData,
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function (obj) {
               alert("fail");
            }
      });
});
```

So some of the ticks are...
Date(1561262400000)
Date(1563854400000)
Date(1561867200000)
Date(1564459200000)
I want to be able to encode the list and still have it return the correct dates

Comment: There is usually no problem with serialization of DateTime itself, are you sure you are setting the value? How do you create this DateTime when you assign it?

Comment: So the object that's in the list is a 'Transaction'. There is a separate page that creates these transactions and one of the fields is a Date input field. The page in question is for viewing these transactions as a table and being able to export. I know the value is set because in the same View page i use the Model to display the date for the table, this is the ajax call to export it as an excel sheet in the same view page and using the same model.

Comment: Can you investigate the network tab in the browser and see if you are getting correct values for DateTimes there? For the 'Transaction' Rows?

Comment: I edited it and added the ticks I am getting

Comment: If those are the values you use to create the datetime in C# - those values are not ticks.Ticks look like this : 637001922571086046, what you are having is Unix Time.

Comment: So in my controller when I use breakpoints to see whats inside my IEnumerable 'Transactions' list it already sets the DateTime to " {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} ". Is this the default for Unix Time? How would I convert it to the time I need or make it so that in the Javascript it uses a different type of time instead of Unix?

Comment: DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(unixTimeMillisecondsValue)   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTimeOffset_FromUnixTimeMilliseconds_System_Int64_

Comment: Yeah, I found that method but the issue is that when serializing in the view its in Unix Time but when it comes to the controller it converts to a DateTime object so it is not in unix time form but an incorrect date which i said was always '{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}'

Comment: You have several options here. So if I understand correctly, the value you submit from your front end is not deserialized properly when it arrives in the controller? If that's the case you could either send Ticks instead of the UnixTimestamp, or create your Date object differently in javascript. There is no problem with passing a 'long' value for ticks and creating a datetime object in your controller

Comment: You can alternatively convert your Date(unixTimestamp) that you have right now into a DateTime string and pass it as a string to your controller, if you pass '2019-01-01' as a string - it will deserialize it properly into datetime.

Comment: I get what you are saying, I think I would want to manipulate the DateTime object in javascript. The issue is that since its a property of the 'Transaction' and its in an X number of 'Transactions' in an IEnumerable list its not exactly easy to loop through it and access it. I've tried using the @Model.toArray(), toList() and GetEnumerator but I havent been successful in singling out each 'Transaction' Date and manipulating it.

Comment: Use LINQ to select the dates and then iterate through them. var dates = this.collection.map(function(v){
    return v.DateTimeProperty ; // your property
});

Comment: So i tried what you suggested and ran into a problem. I cannot use Javascript methods/techniques on c# objects and vice versa. In order to even do anything for it I have to call '@Model.....' and put quotes around it to even let the code run but that just converts the type of whatever i got into a string making it unusable. I would need to use .Select but again I cannot use c# methods/techniques in javascript, so im kinda stuck.

Comment: You can use the select technique in Javascript.  var dates = this.collection.map(function(v){ return v.DateTimeProperty ; // your property });  this piece of code, replace the 'collection' with your collection and change the DateTimeProperty to your variable name, then iterate through collection, or set the appropriate values before calling the controller

Answer (score 0):

So I think it has already been covered that javascript Date using milliseconds from the UTC epoch `1/1/1970` where C# uses 100 nanosecond ticks from `01/01/0001`. There are two solid options for dealing with this. The first would be to create your own JsonConverter and handle the logic there.

The approach I've chosen to display is a bit simpler. Instead of deserializing directly to a DateTime object, lets deserialize to a `long` variable instead. Then, we can add a `DateTime` variable with a custom getter that will handle assignment for you.

```
public class Model
{
    public long time {get;set;}

    public DateTime datetime 
    {
       get
       {
           return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
              .AddMilliseconds(time)
              .ToLocalTime();
       }
    }   
 }
```

Just make sure that the figure coming in deserializes to the long value and then in your C# code only reference the DateTime value

Comment: Yeah, I get what you are saying the issue is that the DateTime object in question is inside a 'Transaction' Class which is inside an IEnumerable list of X 'Transactions' and I cannot manipulate them to export it. It's like this. I go from User Filter in a View->Controller to recieve the filtered data->Different view to display the data -> In the same view export that data-> data comes in as a list of the displayed data. I cannot single out the datetime object in the View since i would need c# to do that when I am in JS.

Comment: Use JsonIgnore attribute on the DateTime object. Javascript will be perfectly happy with receiving the `long` value and turning it back into a Date. It has no knowledge of the type on the model in C# that it came from, all it cares about is that it is a numeric value with the correct property name. Is this Transaction class not your own? In that case I would replicate it with another model using this version, and then cast it to Transaction before sending it back to JS.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making a new model and creating a JS object that matches those models fields exactly. Then I passed the parameters into the new object and called ajax on it. I re-ran the query from the controller which allowed me to still get the parameters I need and it would perform faster if the list got really large versus doing it all front end.